# Relationship between two tables is defined still foreign key constraint error throws in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am facing the error while executing insert or update operation in mysql. I have already define the relation between two tables still it throws error
`Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row:`

```
a foreign key constraint fails ('test'.'system_review', CONSTRAINT 'system_review_ibfk_1' FOREIGN KEY ('SYS_USER_ID') REFERENCES 'user_details' ('USER_ID'))
```

Comment: Have you tried searching on this site? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659691/error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256703/sql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fail

Comment: Please show your SQL statement. That error could be caused by a number of problems, but my best guess is that you are trying to add a row which references a foreign key that does not exist.

Comment: Yes  a foreign key constraint fails (test.system_review, CONSTRAINT system_review_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (SYS_USER_ID) REFERENCES user_details (USER_ID)) //Help me to solve this error

Comment: It show me the error above sentence.

Comment: hey, just a friendly advice : after reading a few of your questions i came to the conclusion that it may be best for you to stick to programming basics for now ... nobody achieves world domination within a few days, you gotta start with the basics - meaning : no databases (at all), no other language than .... say, PHP or something, no complex code. Start with hello-world websites and work your way up from there. Forget about SQL and foreign key constraints for now, databases can be very complex beasts ... you gotta understand algorithms first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you have set Relationship between your two tables. And you are trying to update base record id, which is used by your child table.